# How to deal with a typeface with the wrong character for "inverted question mark"? (Google Quicksand)

Tags: fonts

I am using Quicksand font from Google, and now that I am in the internationalization process, I realized the spanish inverted question mark is not correctly represented.

Is it possible to fix this easily?

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Quicksand

[image]

Comment: This may be in the wrong forum. It sounds like this may be better in graphicdesign.stackexchange.

Comment: I think this doesn't belong here. I recommend  you to send feedback to Google. You probable know you can do it with Javascript, matching that symbol and changing it to another similar font or rotated it, although this is not a nice solution.

Comment: This is almost certainly a conscious choice with the quicksand font, so I would suggest finding a different font to use, if you don't like this one in its entirety.  That aside, this question should be more for stackoverflow, so I'm migrating it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the "wrong character", this is what the designers of Quicksand wanted as inverted question mark. So if you want a different shape: use subsetting and *exclude* the inverted question mark, and then fall back to a font that has the shape you do want.

Also, without any additional details on what context you're actually in (feel free to update your question with that information) it's impossible to tell you how to do that, or even if there are better solutions (on the web, for instance, you can simply have a single-character font with the exact inverted question mark you want, listed as "first font to use" and then use Quicksand as fallback. That way you'll always use your own preferred version)